# Bayesian Networks: Structure Learning in Python is extremely slow compared to R

Tags: python, bayesian-networks, bnlearn, pomegranate, pgmpy

I'm currently working on a problem to do image classification on images using Bayesian Networks. I have tried using `pomegranate`, `pgmpy` and `bnlearn`. My dataset contains more than 200,000 images, on which I perform some feature extraction algorithm and get a feature vector of size 1026.

pgmpy

```
from pgmpy.models import BayesianModel
from pgmpy.estimators import HillClimbSearch, BicScore, K2Score
est = HillClimbSearch(feature_df, scoring_method=BicScore(feature_df[:20]))
best_model = est.estimate()
edges = best_model.edges()
model = BayesianModel(edges)
```

pomegranate

```
from pomegranate import *
model = BayesianNetwork.from_samples(feature_df[:20], algorithm='exact')
```

bnlearn

```
library(bnlearn)
df <- read.csv('conv_encoded_images.csv')
df$Age = as.numeric(df$Age)
res <- hc(df)
model <- bn.fit(res,data = df)
```

The program written in `bnlearn` in R completes running in couple of minutes, while the `pgmpy` runs for hours and pomegranate freezes my system after a few minutes. You can see from my code that I'm giving first 20 rows for training in both `pgmpy` and `pomegranate` programs, while `bnlearn` takes the whole dataframe. Since I am doing all my image preprocessing and feature extraction in python, it is difficult for me to switch between R and python for training.

My data contains continuous values ranging from 0 to 1. I've also tried discretizing the data to 0's and 1's, which didn't resolve the issue.

Is there any way I can speed up training in these python packages or am I doing anything wrong in my code?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Edit:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HbAqDQ6Uv1417zPFMgWBInC7-gz233j2/view?usp=sharing

This is dataset with 300 columns and ~40000 rows. In case you want to try reproducing the output.

Comment: Are you sure that pgmpy and pomegranate can learn the structure for Gaussian data -- perhaps they are just converting each variable to a large number of states hence large cpt's, memory issues, then slow? As for speed, bnlearn is coded in C so is quite fast... what are the python packages coded in ? (quick comment -- are you sure that your bounded [0,1] data, which you call continuous is approximately Gaussian?)

Comment: ... i have seen people calling r::bnlearn from python which would allow you to stay within the python environment (in fact iirc someone.people have written a python wrapper for bnlearn)

Comment: I thought the same about continuous data, which is why I discretized the data into 0's and 1's. There's a bnlearn package in python which is a pgmpy wrapper than R one. Also I tried using rpy2 package in python to run R code. But I was facing error where python could not load R.dll, even though it was in the path. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I wrote a greedy structure learning algorithm to improve the speed. So the quality of the model dropped.